# How do I send a request to a specific server that has the same IP?

Tags: ip

So for example if I query a DNS lookup to 8.8.8.8, the closest server to me will reply, but what if I want another server to reply?

Comment: You can't, you have no control over external connectivity for that IP address. You would need to use an alternative address.